# Why are some event handlers triggered by dispatchEvent, but others are not?

Tags: javascript, events, browser, dom-events

There are two basic APIs for event-based JS: event listeners and event handlers.
Event listeners are registered with `addEventListener`,
and event handlers are registered with an API like `target.onfoobar = (ev) => { ... }`.
Events can then be dispatched with `dispatchEvent`.
But it's not clear to me how/when/whether `dispatchEvent` calls event handlers.

My initial mental model was that event handlers are called at the end of `dispatchEvent`.
That is, `dispatchEvent` would look something like this:

```js
EventTarget.prototype.dispatchEvent = function(event) {
  // First dispatch to this.listeners, then:
  const handler = this['on'+event.type];
  if (handler) handler(event);
};
```

Sometimes, `dispatchEvent` does call the event handler:

```js
window.onclick = () => console.log("this IS called!!");
window.dispatchEvent(new Event("click"));
```

But other times, `dispatchEvent` does *NOT* call the event handler:

```js
window.onxyz = () => console.log("this is NOT called!!");
window.dispatchEvent(new Event("xyz"));
```

I don't know how to explain this disparity.
What is the difference between these two cases?
Is it that `click` is a "standard" event type,
but `xyz` is not?
If so, what constitutes a "standard" event type,
and how does `dispatchEvent` know the difference?

Comment: `on` prefix for a property has no special meaning - `onclick` is a defined method on *some* things, like HTML elements ... `onxyz` is just a property name - i.e. your "mental modal" is flawed ... anyway ... if you say `onclick=fna` then `onclick=fnb` ... only `fnb` gets called ... then how would `addEventListener` fit your model? since you can have as many `eventListener`s as you like!

Answer (score 2):

It's because `onclick` is part of the [`HTMLElement` interface](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#htmlelement) (via its include of [GlobalEventHandlers](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#globaleventhandlers), which in turn refers to the [UI Events specification](https://w3c.github.io/uievents/#event-type-click)), and `onxyz` is not. `onxyz` is just your own expando property with no connection to events as far as the browser knows.

Custom events *are* supported, they just don't have their own special property, so you have to use the appropriate event registration method (`addEventListener` in modern systems, `attachEvent` in obsolete versions of Internet Explorer):

```js
window.addEventListener("xyz", () => console.log("this IS called!!"));
window.dispatchEvent(new Event("xyz"));
```

Comment: why it triggers only once? then when it is called again it does not do anything?